# How do I select an item from a json using codenameone Result?

Tags: codenameone

I have this JSON

```
  "DocumentType": {
    "propertyName": "DocumentType",
    "propertyType": "Text",
    "propertyValue": "Fire"
  },
  "adsfsadf": {
    "propertyName": "adsfsadf",
    "propertyType": "Text",
    "propertyValue": "sfsfdffsd"
  }
```

I want to search and retrieve the node that has `propertyName="DocumentType"`? I have tried

```
result.get("//@propertyName='DocumentType'/..")
```

And also tried

```
result.get("//propertyName[text()='DocumentType'/..")
```

And get a null object each time.

Comment: I had this same problem trying to access properties.  Eventually I just filed a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code

```
JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
Map<String, Object> myMap = p.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(YOUR JSON INPUT STREAM));
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> myList = (ArrayList<Map<String,String>>)myMap.get("DocumentType");
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, String> dtls = myList.get(i);
        String prop = dtls.get("propertyName"));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to use the result feature. I already had this working.